# Unable to begin Security Review

Tags: security-review

I have a lightning App which I have scanned using the Checkmarx app, along with a scan with ZAP. However, when I go to the security review tab, the `Start Review` button is greyed out and the `Update Payment` button is showing. I have updated the payment info and it was accepted, however this did not allow me to start the review. Has anyone else experienced this issue?

Comment: Have you had a business plan reviewed and accepted?

Comment: The only thing not completed is the Business & Product Information.